# Source getting modiefied when I modify target object of BeanUtils.CopyProperties

Tags: java, list, clone, spring-framework-beans

I have copied one object into another with help of

```
BeanUtils.CopyProperties(Src,Dest);

From : package org.springframework.beans;
```

Now further in logic , with help of iterator I modify the list inside Dest object.

I want src object to be as it is.

But I see a weird behavior.
My Src is also getting modified.

What can be the reason ?

**Example:**
src and Dest have list:   [Mango , Apple]

I removed Mango from Dest with help of iteartor.

later I see
Src have [Apple]
Dest have [Apple]

Is it happening because of shallow copy ?

Comment: "later I see
Src have [Mango]
Dest have [Apple] " You would say  "later I see
Src have [Apple]
Dest have [Apple] "  ?

Comment: yes sir  i see [Apple] right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to copy the `List` field but clone it in the new copied object.

`BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object source, Object target)` doesn't explicit clearly in its javadoc but it does a shallow copy from a object to another one.

It means that in the `target` object, the `List` field will reference the same object that which one in the `source` object.

So modifying the `List` field from the one or the other one object will be reflected in the other.

To create a new List, you should create a new List instance that contains the actual elements in the source `List` and assign it to the `List` field in the target object.

For example :

```
MyObject source = ...;
MyObject target = ...;

BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);
...
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(source.getList());
target.setList(newList);
```

Comment: thanks @davidxxx I understood it must be because of shallow copy, do you know any method for deep copy ?

Comment: You are welcome :) You can do it manually with a ArrayList constructor as in my example. I was editing.

Comment: or would you suggest custom method ? as above ?

Comment: copyProperties() is rather fast. If you want to avoid writing some boiler plate code, you may use libraries that do deep copies but these are more expensive in terms of processing time.